# Force Redirect to Another Page when First Time Login in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

currently I'm building web apps for local. When I create new user, I'm setup the user with Default Password. And I want to, if the User login with the Default Password it will redirect to Change Password Page. And User will not be able to access any page until they change the password.

My current workaround is checking in each controller, is there any Smart way to do this?

Here's some code after doing login

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] LoginViewModel vm, string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await repository.Login(vm);
        if (result.IsSuccess)
        {
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, result.Data,
                new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                    IsPersistent = false
                });

            if (vm.Password != Password.DefaultPassword)
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(UserController.NewPassword));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = result.ErrorMessage;
        }
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

For the other Controller, we always check the Password from session. If the Password is same as Default Password we redirect it to `NewPassword` Page

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably redirect from the `Login` method in the `AccountController`. But we would need more details on your implementation

Comment: @JHBonarius i add the details for the current implementation

Comment: Clear.... I think you'll have to implement a sort of "rights"/"roles" system. I.e. some users only have the rights to view certain pages. I think that scales the best. Otherwise you need some persistence to see if the user still has the default password (as you don't want to check it every time) and maybe redirect using some custom middleware controller.

Comment: @JHBonarius any sample for that custom middleware controller?

Comment: no.... that's what "custom" means. it has to be adapted to your needs.

Comment: Maybe give a base "User" role when the password has been changed? And add ```[Authorize(Roles = "User")]``` whenever you need to check that the users creation is 'complete'.

Comment: IMHO don't check for a default password. Add a new DB column for "Change the password on next login". Then you need a special auth policy that applies to these users, so they can't do anything until their password has been changed. (https://kenhaggerty.com/articles/article/aspnet-core-31-must-change-password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JHBonarius said, my current workaround now is to use Custom Middleware for Redirecting to New Password Page.

My middleware look like this:

```cs
public class CheckPasswordMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public CheckPasswordMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path != "/User/NewPassword" && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userId = context.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                var dbContext = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
                var passwordHash = await dbContext.User.Where(x => x.Id.ToLower() == userId.ToLower()).Select(x => x.Password).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                if (Hash.Verify(Password.DefaultPassword, passwordHash))
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/User/NewPassword");
                }
            }
        }

        await next(context);
    }
}
```

and now I can get rid the check in my other controller, and my Login will just look like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] LoginViewModel vm, string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await repository.Login(vm);
        if (result.IsSuccess)
        {
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, result.Data,
                new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                    IsPersistent = false
                });
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = result.ErrorMessage;
        }
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

Hope this help anyone who want to achieve the same goals.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can store user password using `session` as below

```cs
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Password", vm.password);
```

Then create a filter to check if the user login with the Default Password or not

```cs
public class PasswordFilter: IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly ISession _session;
        public PasswordFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {

            if (_session.GetString("Password") == Password.DefaultPassword)
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectResult(nameof(UserController.NewPassword));

            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, you can use this filter by adding this attribute to your controllers

```cs
[TypeFilter(typeof(PasswordFilter))]
```

I hope this approach achieves your goal.